# How to resize a UITableViewCell's accessoryView based on size of cell?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

Is it possible for a UITableViewCell's accessory view to be sized based on the size of the UITableViewCell that owns it? How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Is this a custom accessory view or one of the standard ones?  The standard ones only centre in the cell (which is still quite useful) rather than resize.  However if you push a UISwitch or other custom view as an accessory view then these might resize.